# Drawing overlapping clusters using javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js

We want to plot clusters of data using javascript. We believe D3.js gives best graphing capabilities. But I am not able to find examples for overlapping clusters, meaning, some data points could belong more than one groups.  If we are using circle for visualization of a group, then for overlapping groups, circles should overlap.

Some links for cluster plotting

1. [Link](http://mbostock.github.io/d3/talk/20111018/cluster.html)
2. [Link](http://www.ericbullington.com/articles/2012/01/31/kmeans-visualization)

Format of Data is as follows,

```
Group1 :  D1,D2,D3,D4,D5
Group2 :  D4,D7,D8,D9
Group3 :  D1,D9,D11,D12,D13
```

Can somebody please suggest some good javascript libraries for plotting overlapping clusters ?

Comment: Sounds a bit like a Venn Diagram and here's an example of one implemented in [D3](http://www.benfrederickson.com/2013/05/09/venn-diagrams-with-d3.js.html)

Comment: The answer to this question depends entirely on what format your data is in. If you have the assignments of points to clusters, drawing circles that cover them shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: Please see updated question for format of the data

Comment: Ok, so how are the coordinates of the points computed? Given those, you can easily compute the position and dimensions of a circle that covers them.

Comment: each point has some double value (single dimension) associated with it

Comment: So would it be acceptable for your application to take the range of values for a single cluster and draw a circle at the mid-point and appropriate radius?

Comment: may be yes,actually distance/double value associated with point (which belongs to ClusterA) has different value in ClusterB

Comment: At this point it would be really helpful to have a concrete example :)